# Calculus of variations with delayed/shifted variable

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations, functional-calculus

How can the following optimization problem be solved?
$$
\min_{y} \quad \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2y(x)\mathrm{d}x,\\
\mathrm{s.t.} \quad y(x)\leq \alpha y(x-d),\\
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y(x)\mathrm{d}x=1,
$$
where $y$ is a real-valued function over $\mathbb{R}$. This is a problem of optimizing the second moment of a distribution with a non-classical constraint $y(x)\leq \alpha y(x-d)$ which makes it a bit ugly. Happy to hear what you think. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics! Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say what your thoughts on this problem are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Is there any relation between $y$ and $p$?

Comment: Oh man! That's was a bad typo by me. Thanks for catching it. Please see the updated formulation.